# Iteração com variável do tipo 'TIME'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um projeto no qual necessito realizar um laço que aumente minuto a minuto de uma variável a partir de dois horários informados.

Pensei na lógica da seguinte maneira:

```
 vHoraInicial = '13:30'
 vHoraFinal   = '15:00'

While vHoraInicial <= vHoraFinal:
        print (vHoraInicial)
        vHoraInicial = vHorainicial + 1
```

> Resultado do print:
> 13:30
>
> 13:31
>
> 13:32
>
> ...
>
> 15:00

Mas não sei as funções que me auxiliem a manipular variável 'TIME'. Alguem tem alguma idéia?

Obrigado

Comment: E como irá funcionar em situações em que vira o dia ? É suposto esses casos estarem contemplados ?

Comment: Na verdade não Isac, só quero verificar no máximo de 00:00 até 23:59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da maneira que está, você não está trabalhando com horários, mas sim com *string*. Para nós acaba sendo a mesma coisa, mas para o computador são completamente diferentes. Para trabalhar com horários, você precisará do módulo [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=5, day=8, hour=13, minute=30)
end = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=5, day=8, hour=15, minute=0)
interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

while start <= end:
    print(start)
    start += interval
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/TomatoHighlevelCategory) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/APIUul) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/2e74c6fe018f84995f65e0de4cd705d3)</sup>

Perceba que, trabalhando com horários, você precisa definir a data, visto que se o horário exceder 23:59:59, o dia será alterado. Se existe a garantia que sempre será no mesmo dia o horário de início e fim, para fins práticos, você pode definir a data como constante e, ao invés de exibir diretamente a data, formatá-la, `print(format(start, '%H:%M:%S'))`.

Comment: Anderson excelente, funcionou aqui! Para a função que irei utilizar tenho a garantia de que nunca irá ultrapassar o dia, portanto, vou manter a data fixa. Muito obrigado amigo!